# Target style null when cursor leave the screen on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have some issue with Firefox when my cursor leave the current window.

In the sample of the code I release the old target style, which works fine on IE and Chrome, but not on Firefox if my cursor leave the current window the "instance.Target.style" is undefined.

Have I done something wrong, or Firefox choose to have a different behaviour ?

```
function WidgetGrid_MouseMove(domEvent,instance)
{
    // Get the target element
    var target = domEvent.target;

    // Release the old target
    if (instance.Target && instance.Target != target)
    {
        instance.Target.style.cursor = "";
    }

    // Set the new target
    instance.Target = domEvent.target;

    // Do other thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
instance.Target.style.cursor = null;
```

Different browsers check for empty variables differently. That is why it is good practice to do something like:

```
var instance = instance.Target.style.cursor;

if (instance === "" || instance === null){
   //do something.....
}
```

Comment: I have an error on "instance.Target.style" so I can't set the cursor property with neither null or "". With the check (instance.Target.style != null) everything working on my side, but I'm curious about FF behaviour.

Comment: Firefox simply has a different JS interpreter that does not treat empty strings as null. Null is a necessary declaration in Firefox if you want to test if the existing variable is indeed "empty".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

For example, if you declare `var foo;` without assigning any value to it - the value is null by default - which is actually a literal that you can test against. Once you assign a value to the variable, the literal becomes the new value. You can think of `null` as a placeholder for `Nope, nothing stored in here`